# Excel Unexpected Error when creating a QueryTable

Tags: excel, vba

I'm getting an unexpected error when creating a QueryTable in MS Excel.
[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1zSbT.jpg)

---

Stack Trace:

bei Microsoft.Mashup.Client.Excel.NativeExcelFunctionsBase.ValidateResult(Int32 result, Int32[] expectedValues)

bei Microsoft.Mashup.Client.Excel.NativeExcelFunctionsMSI.Microsoft.Mashup.Client.Excel.INativeExcelFunctions.GetConnectionProperties(IntPtr workbookPointer, String connectionName)

bei Microsoft.Mashup.Client.Excel.NativeEventHandler.<>c__DisplayClass27.b__25()

bei Microsoft.Mashup.Host.Document.ExceptionHandlerExtensions.HandleExceptions(IExceptionHandler exceptionHandler, Action action)

This is my code:

```
    With Tabelle1.ListObjects.Add(xlSrcExternal, Source:=Connectionstring, Destination:=Range("$A$2")).QueryTable
    .CommandType = xlCmdSql
    .CommandText = "SELECT * FROM MySchema.MyTable"
    .RowNumbers = True
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .BackgroundQuery = True
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .PreserveColumnInfo = True
    .ListObject.DisplayName = "MyTable"
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
```

The Database Connection is working and Excel is also loading the Table Data to my worksheet, but I always get the Error Message.
Can anybody guess the problem ?

Comment: You should include the error message in your question as text and it would be a good idea to also provide an English translation so that we can look it up.